# zsh grep pattern matching for ^ not working

Tags: regex, git, zsh

For git, I have many branches that I start off with `temp`, so to filter all the temporary branches, I tried:

`git branch | grep "^temp"`

However, I am not getting any result.

If I just run `git branch`, I get the following:

```
temp/github-fix
temp/mismatches
test/temp
```

I want to just match the first two, but not the last one.

Comment: Are you sure there aren't spaces at the start of the lines?

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley and here I was banging away on this for almost 15 mins thinking I was completely wrong about regex in grep. Anyone know why there's an indentation here apart for just aesthetic reasons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `--list` followed by a pattern to list the branches you want.

```
git branch --list 'temp*'
```

Comment: This seems like a cleaner solution

Answer (score 2):

as @WumpusQ.Wumbley pointed out, `git branch` output usually starts with whitespace, try this, `git branch|grep '^\s*temp'`

Comment: Hah, can't believe I missed that. Thanks to you and @wumpus

Comment: Glad to help, we've all been there... :)

Comment: If the HEAD is on a branch `temp/xxx`, `grep '^\s*temp'` will miss this current branch, because git branch will highlight it with an asterisk.